# MongoDB count() mismatch on a sharded cluster

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I have loaded a collection consisting of 24,895,212 elements into MongoDB.   I have sharding enabled with 5 shards.   The data is evenly sharded across the 5 shards.  The Balancer is not running currently (sh.isBalancerRunning()  returns false).

Based on the documentation,  once the balancer completes sharding,  I should be able to run the db.collection.count() command to get a row count.  However if I do that I get 25,245,767 rows.   Not sure where the extra 350,555 rows are coming from.   Note that if I run the command:

```
mongos>  db.collection.find({}).itcount()
```

I get the correct count of 24,895,212 but the problem is that this command runs for about 15 minutes...

Any ideas on where I am going wrong,  why i have the 350,555 row diff?   I also tried to run the orphan cleanup process by issuing the command:

```
mongos> db.runCommand( { cleanupOrphaned: "<db>.<collection>" } )
```

However this process ran for about 9 hours over night and didn't finish in the morning...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since cleaning up orphan documents(caused due to failed migrations) did not complete it is quite possible they still exist. Moreover there is a open bug: [Sharded collection counts (on primary) can report too many results](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3645)

This bug is due to be fixed in 2.7. I think you are facing the same issue.

Comment: That's exactly it.  As per SERVER-3645,   if I run "db.collection.find({}).explain().n"  I get the correct count. So hoping this will be fixed in 2.7.   Performing a cleanupOrphaned command is not an option for me since it runs for so many hous, and I need to refresh my collection more frequently than that...